# Laravel package installation without composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

How can I manually configure the laravel package without composer. I have a project in which I got error when installing Intervention package. Please suggest me Is it possible or not.

Comment: Are there any details you can provide about your setup and your project?

Comment: I think you need to focus on fixing the error, as Laravel uses Composer extensively, and once you understand Composer you will realise how important and useful it is.

Answer (score 0):

While you definitely can, for instance, simply clone their GitHub repo, eg.:

```
git clone https://github.com/Intervention/image.git
```

And then manually include corresponding files (classes) in your code, I wouldn't recommend it - composer generates autoload files, but this package will be ignored since it's not in composer.json. You will end up adding manual require()s somewhere in your code.

I would say try to fix your composer package issue first, and only if it cannot be helped - download and include Intervention manually